# Does someone going to college in another state need to file Virginia Taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, massachusetts, virginia

Our son (19) goes to college in MA while we live in VA.  This year for the first time we did not include him as a dependent in our 1040.   During 2022 he had an internship &  research assistantship both in MA for which he was paid ~12k.  Federal and MA taxes were deducted on both incomes.   He spent ~10mos in MA and ~2mos in VA but there wasn't a VA-based income.  Does he need to file VA-taxes?

Comment: He's still a domiciliary resident: https://www.tax.virginia.gov/residency-status

Comment: Thx! He is a dependent on my medical insurance plan obtained through my employer.  Are we required to add him as a dependent on our coverage?

Comment: Has your son switched their residence to Massachusetts? Registered to vote? Registered their car? Claim in state tuition? Do you still provide half their support?

Comment: Side note: Even if they are still VA residents in all these things, Massachusetts may still call them for jury duty. I took three days off from my thesis  -- I could have postponed it, but I actually appreciated the excuse to take a break.